# Java - Skip line of mocked s3Client class from a junit

Tags: java, mockito, knox-amazon-s3-client

I need to be able to skip over the s3Client line below when myMethod is executed from a junit. MyClass is NOT mocked, nor is myMethod:

```
MyClass {
    myMethod(String bucketName, String path) {

        // do stuff

        // skip below when mocked in junit
        s3Client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, path));

        // more stuff
    {
{
```

In the junit I have:

```
s3Client = mock(AmazonS3.class);
when(s3Client.deleteObject(any(DeleteObjectRequest.class))).thenReturn(null);
```

The "when" does not compile:

```
when(T) cannot be applied to void. reason: no instances of type variable T exist so that void conforms to T.
```

Again, I just need to skip this line when from a junit. Any solutions appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `deleteObjects` vs `deleteObject` like the error message says?

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for catch. Still error now but different. Updating post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked:

```
doNothing().when(s3Client).deleteObject(any(DeleteObjectRequest.class));
```